# Powershell command to change registry value in a subfolder using C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am working on something that is supposed to change a registry data value. So the user clicks on a button and it changes the value. Im using C# to run the command in powershell.

When I use this...

```
string script = "Set-ItemProperty -path \HKLM:\\ -name rname -value + new";
```

It changes the value in that MAIN folder without a problem but when I try to change a value in one of its SUBFOLDERS like so..

```
string script = "Set-ItemProperty -path \HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon -name rname -value + new";
```

It does nothing. The value doesnt change at all.

Can someone help?

Comment: If you are working in c#, why use Powershell to work with the registry?

Comment: Wouldnt I have to use powershell to access it? What is another way? I dont really work with C# or Powershell much. I found a code that did something a little similar to what I want but not exactly so I used that as a base and have been tweaking it a little.

Comment: Yes, there is a Registry class in .Net, see the answer from Will Eddins below.

Comment: @Ello I was just posting to your other question some help but you deleted it!!    :)   Anyway here is a potentially helpful link to the MSDN RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey documentation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411615.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better option may be to use the [Registry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#:

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\...", "rname", value);
```

It should accomplish the same thing, but in a much easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in C#, you'll need to escape the backslashes also. For example, instead of `HKLM:\software\Micro...`, you need `HKLM:\\software\\Micro...`

Comment: I actually do have that in my code. For some reason it didnt show it that way in my post but now it does.